# Unable to use rsnapshot to sync non-owned files but able to do it with plain rsync command

Tags: ssh, permissions, rsync, rsnapshot

I am trying to use `rsnapshot` to sync remote file to my own computer. However, I have some trouble when I need to access files which are not owned by user who is SSH-ing to the remote machine.

My `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` looks like this:

```
config_version  1.2
snapshot_root   /shared/.backup/
cmd_cp          /bin/cp
cmd_rm          /bin/rm
cmd_rsync       /usr/bin/rsync
cmd_ssh         /usr/bin/ssh
cmd_logger      /usr/bin/logger
cmd_du          /usr/bin/du

retain      hourly  6
retain      daily   7
retain      weekly  4
retain      monthly 3

verbose     2
loglevel    5
logfile     /shared/.backup/rsnapshot.log

ssh_args    -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 62222

# BACKUP DEFINITIONS
backup  username@10.10.11.11:/          dev.local.root/     exclude_file=/shared/.backup/exclude.root,+rsync_long_args=--rsync-path='sudo rsync',rsync_short_args=-zalhHx
```

After running `rsnapshot hourly` I see this error:

```
bash: sudo rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rsnapshot encountered an error! The program was invoked with these options:
/usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: /usr/bin/rsync returned 127 while processing username@10.10.11.11:/
```

If I check my `rsnapshot.log` file, I can see that `rsnapshot` tried this command:

`/usr/bin/rsync -zalhHx --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/shared/.backup/exclude.root --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 62222 username@10.10.11.11:/ /shared/.backup/hourly.0/dev.local.root/`

If I try to run the same command in terminal, I get this error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: username@10.10.11.11:/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.0]
```

However, if I put quotation marks around `--rsh` part everything works fine:

`/usr/bin/rsync -zalhHx --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/shared/.backup/exclude.root --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 62222' username@10.10.11.11:/ /shared/.backup/hourly.0/dev.local.root/`

**Some facts**

- On remote machine, there is a line `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` in sudoers file.
- I can normally SSH to the remote machine with my SSH key.
- I can invoke `sudo` commands on server without being asked for a password.
- I cannot SSH as root to remote machine because of `PermitRootLogin on` and `AllowUsers username` in `sshd_config`
- If I try `ssh username@10.10.11.11 -p 62222 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa which rsync`, the output is `/usr/bin/rsync`
- If I try `ssh username@10.10.11.11 -p 62222 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa echo $PATH`, the output is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

So.... My question is simple: how do I properly construct this `rsync` command in `rsnapshot`?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error,
I was forced to specify a manual script

```
--rsync-path='sudo rsync' > --rsync-path='/usr/local/bin/rsync'
```

with /usr/local/bin/rsync on remote

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/rsync "$@"
```

Comment: There is usually no space after `#!`. I would avoid it - just in case some systems are strict about the format.